# Publishing an item in Workflow through a nested RenderComponentPresentation not showing changes in Workflow

Tags: 2011, publishing, workflow, dwt

We have a Component Template that uses `@@RenderComponentPresentation(CID,CTID)@@` from Dreamweaver mediator on linked Component and a Component Template ID that is pulled from the Component metadata.

It works great for the output that we need, however when we got into Workflow, the content is not able to be published under the minimum approval status to the configured Publication Target while in Workflow.

I know through TOM.NET you can set the `IncludeWorkflow=True` option, but can this be done, or something like it, in the DWT to allow for the user to publish on demand? Do we need to have the publish step included in Workflow? Are we going to have the same issue if we publish through Workflow?

> Note: System works as desired when a Page is created with the just the underlying Component Presentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Update** All the content that we publish is static, no dynamic component presentations. I will be trying out a CoreService call and setting the IncludeWorkflow to see if the content will come out with the content in workflow.

Comment: **Update** I tried the CoreService call to publish the page and set the IncludeWorkflow to see if the content will come out with the content in workflow, it did not. I have a support ticket open to Tridion as well. I will reply back with what they say.

Comment: **Update** Support has classified this as a defect and I am waiting on a response from R&D. If they come back with a HotFix, i will post the reference. I have also asked them if this affects 2013 SP1 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL support has released Hotfix `CM_2011.1.2.87726` for Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2. I have asked about this issue in 2013 SP1 but no response yet. Thanks all for your suggestions!

Comment: SDL support has also released Hotfix `CM_2013.1.0.87908` along with `CME_2013.1.0.87280` to published linked Components.

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine that this is expected behaviour, especially if you are dealing with dynamic component presentations, as you certainly wouldn't wish to publish content that isn't approved.

You most likely need some logic in your workflow to include the linked items as part of the workflow process, but it's first working out what your desired logic should be.

If this we're version 2013 of the CMS you were working with i'd recommend looking into 
**bundles** this will allow you to group content and have them all process together through workflow.  I see you're using 2011, but are perhaps considering upgrading your version, i'd recommend this approach over building your own workflow additions.

Answer (score 1):

I did not completely understand the note. However, if I understand correctly the question is how to ensure that during publishing it picks up versions which are in workflow. Firstly I would like to point out that during publishing if IncludeWorkflow is set to true, any items page/components or linked components, if they are in workflow and have the necessary minimum approval status it is going to be picked. If you want to publish it as a step in your workflow you should create an automatic activity which publishes the items ensuring that IncludeWorkflow:true. However, if you want to ensure that while publishing through UI you would like to include the items in workflow you are out of luck. It is possible since 2013 to set this option in the publish dialog in the UI, in 2011 you have to create your own UI extension to achieve this. Or may be some gurus can point to an existing UI extension.

Comment: I guess you could use the Event System to turn that flag to true?